# FindOneAndUpdate with the model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried two ways to overwrite an existing document if its not exist.

## 1st way

This code didn't work and throws this error on every update:

> **error:** *After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('***') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('***78')"*

```
exports.loginUser = function (req, res) {
var newUser = new userModel(req.body);
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, newUser ,{ new: true, 

upsert:true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, function (err, userUpdate) {

return res.json(userUpdate);

}
```

## 2nd Way

Directly inserting the request `body` which work well. But I dont want to do that, because `body` can have junk:

```
exports.loginUser = function (req, res) {
var newUser = new userModel(req.body);
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, req.body ,{ new: true, 

upsert:true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, function (err, userUpdate) {

return res.json(userUpdate);

}
```

So can anybody suggest me how to do `findOneAndUpdate` with the model instead of request body.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) method:

```
var newUser = new userModel(req.body);

newUser.update(newUser, { upsert:true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json('Cannot save user');
    }

    res.json(newUser);
});
```

There is no need to use the `new:true` option because `newUser` will always contain the updated or inserted document

Comment: If i use save then i am getting error as "duplicate key error index:" because as per mongoose doc save does consider the _id. if it present then it will give error for duplication.

Comment: There is another way to do that by calling update method on the model instance, it could accept a model instance too, not only object, see my updated answer

Comment: `userModel.update({email: req.body.email}, {fullName: 'rt'}, {upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, function (err, userUpdate) { if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.json('Cannot save user');
    }

    res.json(newUser);
});  `                                                                                                                                               
**it work well when i  try to update the single field, but not work if i try to update the whole model object. in my case which is newUser variable**

Comment: Yes it work if you try to update the whole document, and in my example I used the model instance `newUser.update` not the model as you do `userModel.update`, plz try it

Comment: i tried this way to update model and collection but getting error saying **duplicate key error index: sample2.user.$email_1 dup key**

Comment: its giving the unique index error because in model i have consider email to be unique. And if i try to do without unique property in model then it repeat the entry irrespective of previous store entry. Does it has any alternative if i define unique and still want to update if not exist

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `new` because that will create a new `_id`, so instead you should do:

```
exports.loginUser = function(req, res) {
    var newUser = req.body; // here remove the new
    userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email: req.body.email },
        newUser,
        { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
        function(err, userUpdate) {
            return res.json(userUpdate);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I already gave this solution in question in 2nd way, but i want to avoid this cause i want to map it with model they check on some condition like mandatory fields.

Comment: 2way always use `new userModel(req.body)`